# Can I use "pretty", "quite" etc with weather?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Can I use "pretty", "quite" etc with weather?
Not long ago I've been texting with someone and wanted to say "It's pretty freezing here" but hesitated (I'm not native speaker as you might guess), so I decided to ask here if it's correct to say like this.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Look at the Cambridge dictionary online for “pretty” and you will find definitions and good examples. If you still have difficulty, come and ask us again.

Comment: Logically, of course, the temperature either _is_ below freezing point or it _isn't_ - but if you are using the term loosely to mean 'cold', you can qualify it.

Comment: Pretty is used when something is not too extreme. Pretty cool is ok, pretty cold is ok, but freezing is already very cold so pretty freezing is unusual. Most people would use a stronger word than pretty. Perhaps absolutely freezing. Many alternatives are not used in polite company.